# What phones ( on Android, of course) are able to correctly display the CID for the neighboring cell towers in 3g, 4g?

Tags: java, android

Tell me, please , what phones ( on Android, of course) are able to correctly display the CID for the neighboring cell towers for 3g and 4g. I mean, I tried to get this information on the Sony Z3 and Samsung S5, however, they give incorrect data.

Comment: How do you know it's incorrect?

Comment: For example, functions return either CID like 65536 (overload) or return nothing...